# "Next week" vs. "in the next few days"

Tags: prepositions, time

According to grammar that we don't put any preposition before *next week*, *year*, *month* etc. but in one of the Outcome books I found this sentence:

> Passengers who are flying **IN** the next few days should ring their airline.

Could you please someone explain it to me?

Comment: It's "in _the_  next _few_ days"...that is different.

Comment: Thank you for your time. But anyway I don't understand the difference:) Sorry. If you could explain it more I will really appreciate that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just to make things worse, 'We are leaving in a few days' / 'We are leaving in the next few days' need the preposition, but 'We are leaving a few days from now' must not have one.

Comment: thank you all that you are trying to help me understand :)
your first example I understand why there is but the next one with a proposition I can't understand why :) sorry
I'm trying to find some grammar explanation but so far I haven't found yet

Answer (score 1):

From what I have found, we do use prepositions in most time phrases, whether it be "in", "on", "at" or another preposition. What separates today, tomorrow and yesterday is that they are compound words which already have a preposition built into them. E.g. "to". There are other phrases which don't have prepositions such s "these days", I think this is just a linguistic phenomenon which has come to be accepted but, to my knowledge, does not have a grammatical reason to not using a preposition.

Comment: This has all the potential of being a good answer, but you need to show some citations and sources to support it. Please.